# matlab videoreader skips some frames

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab R2013a for video processing. I have an unusual problem I haven't been able to find an answer to. I am loading a (small) .avi video, about 50 Mb, 15 fps, 240x320 p. I get the number of frames as such:

```
videoname=uigetfile('*.avi');
vidprocess=VideoReader(videoname);
nframes=vidprocess.NumberofFrames;
```

The thing is, the number of frames is wrong, about 15 frames missing. The problem is, I use avidemux to locate some frames of interest within the video, but I get different images for the same frame number from avidemux and matlab. I cross checked the frame numbers and it is matlab videoreader that skips some frames. Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks,

George

Comment: Are you sure that the frames are actually missing as opposed to the number being calculated incorrectly? For example, if Matlab erroneously determined the frame rate and/or the duration of the file and calculated the frame count from these. The difference between 30fps and 29.97fps can add up. Where is the AVI from, how has it been processed/edited, and what is the actual codec?

Comment: It is a possibility I guess. But why would every video player I got displays the correct number of frames? The .avi is from a camera recording software. There has been no processing or editing. I don't know about the codec I am afraid.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to provide much help without the video file in question. As for why Matlab might be different, it's not a user program designed to play a video no matter what even if headers of frames might be corrupted. Matlab expects video files to meet specifications exactly and will generally fail if corruption or invalid data is present.

Comment: Another possible cause of the missing frames could be inter-frame compression in the codec, i.e., data in some frames depends on that in others. Depending on how the file was saved, initial and final frames, may have incomplete data. Video players will often handle this as best they can by interpolation or other means to fill in the missing info. Or they may report the full number of frames, but just play back the complete ones. Matlab, may just grab and report the number full complete frames. Again, all of this is guessing on my part.

Comment: If the missing frames are at the start or end, then you might try editing the video to trim a bit off of the end and/or beginning to see if that fixes the numbering issue.